# C++11's shared_ptr assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have the following code:

```
    #include <memory>

    int main(void)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> currInt(nullptr);

        std::shared_ptr<int> newInt(new int);
        currInt = newInt;

        return 0;
    }
```

It turns out that this isn't valid C++11 (it use to be in the draft versions) and that the assignment constructor now uses move semantics. Something I don't understand.

Could somebody please explain how I'd modify the code above to make it.. work?

Comment: Assignment shouldn't be using move semantics - that's what `unique_ptr` is for, isn't it? And what exactly is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: In C++11 the shared_ptr's copy constructor is deleted in favour of a move constructor. I don't really understand much of move semantics. If you try to compile this in Clang 3.0 you can see the error for yourself.

Comment: I don't belive this is so. Check out [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). To my knowledge, the information it has is up-to-date. Also, this code compiles on GCC 4.6.1. The biggest reason this doesn't make sense to me is the move semantics require that the moved-from object is left in an "empty" state. This is clearly not desirable with a `shared_ptr`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah yes, but according to [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#deleted-special-func), the standard was changed last minute and GCC 4.7 fixes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a copy constructor for `shared_ptr`, otherwise what's the point of a `shared_ptr`?

The [clang link](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#deleted-special-func) by OP is saying that if only the move assignment operator is defined, then the copying constructor will be implicitly deleted, *making the `shared_ptr` not behaving correctly*. This can be seen in the [Boost changeset](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/73202) as well, where the copy assignment operators are *explicitly added* to correct the bug.

You can find the copy assignment operators of `shared_ptr` in §20.7.2.2.3[util.smartptr.shared.assign]/1­–3.

```
shared_ptr& operator=(const shared_ptr& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> shared_ptr& operator=(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> shared_ptr& operator=(auto_ptr<Y>&& r);
```

Comment: Note that only the first one is a _copy_ assignment operator, the latter two are merely assignment operators. /pedantic ;-]